# Como alterar o tamanho da lista do DropdownButton?

Tags: flutter, dropdown, layout, widget, dropdownlist

Sou novo no Flutter e criei um **DropdownButton** no qual funciona perfeitamente. Porém preciso que o mesmo quando aberto, não preencha a tela inteira como mostra a imagem 1 e 2. Preciso que o **DropdownButton** abra da localização atual dele para baixo (mostrado na imagem 3), para que se o usuário se arrependa de ter aberto o **DropdownButton** consiga recolher o **Dropdown** e não seja obrigado a selecionar uma opção para que o **DropdownButton** seja recolhido ou utilizar da opção voltar do próprio aparelho.
Isso é possível ou precisarei usar outro Widget?

Segue meu código abaixo:

```
DropdownButton<String>(
          isExpanded: true,
          value: expansionValue,
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
          iconSize: 28,
          elevation: 16,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          onChanged: (String newValue) {
            setState(() {
              expansionValue = newValue;
            });
          },
          items: <String>['Box-1', 'Box-2', 'Box-3', 'Box-4','Box-5', 'Box-6',
            'Box-7', 'Box-8', "Box-9", "Box-10", "Box-11", "Box-12", "Box-13",
            "Box-14", "Box-15", "Box-16", "Box-17"]
              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
```

Imagem 1

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem 2

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem 3 (como preciso que fique)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse é um problema que o Flutter ainda não resolveu... Como pode ver nessa [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23865). Caso queira aplicar um "workaround" (Famosa Gambiarra) pode tentar o que está sugerido [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53984215/10145630)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Resposta curta:

Oficialmente não tem como atingir o resultado desejado. Tem umas soluções (gambiarras) na internet que adaptam o código original para o seu objetivo.

- Resposta longa:

Pesquisando pelas propriedades da classe [DropDownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) nenhuma aparenta representar o comportamento que você deseja.

Existe a propriedade [itemHeight](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/itemHeight.html), que junto com talvez a [isDense](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/isDense.html) possa ajudar, dependendo da situação, embora esteja longe de ser genérico e ideal (Requer que não existam muitos itens e que o tamanho de cada um seja calculado estaticamente). No seu caso-exemplo já não serviria.

Olhando aqui na rede, achei [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53984215/10746978), em inglês, que retrata exatamente sua situação. A solução apresentada pelo usuário foi criar um DropDownButton Customizado, que é idêntico ao [oficial do Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/1aafb3a8b9/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart#L790), porém com uma propriedade `height` que caso ela esteja definida, envolve o *dialog* de seleção de itens em uma [SizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html) com altura máxima definida. O próprio autor da resposta que mencionei acima forneceu um [Gist](https://gist.github.com/tudor07/9f886102f3cb2f69314e159ea10572e1#file-custom_dropdown-dart-L199) com essa alteração que você pode importar em seu projeto e usar adicionando um prefixo (alias ou apelido) de importação. Nesse exemplo, o prefixo é `custom`:

```
 import 'custom_dropdown.dart' as custom;
[...] 
custom.DropdownButtonFormField(
    height: //Sua Altura aqui
),
[...]

custom.DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text("Sample Tex"),
                value: "any_value",
              ),
```

Essa solução também não é ideal. Cada novidade que a equipe do Flutter adicionar na classe  de DropDownButton não será refletida na sua versão customizada. Essa resposta teve sua última revisão em Setembro de 2019 justamente com atualização deste código, por conta disto.

Uma [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23865) no repositório oficial está aberta sobre esse problema, e existe um comentário de ontem (26/11/2020) ainda pedindo solução. Ou seja, está confirmado que não existe uma maneira oficial de fazer isso, e não se sabe quando vai ser adicionada essa funcionalidade ao framework, porém é algo que já se está ciente e requisitado.

Nesta issue, [um usuário](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23865#issuecomment-638546234) fez uma **nova versão** do código customizado acima, porém adicionando uma nova funcionalidade de `offset` para o topo da página. Isto é, a lista dos itens terá **uma distância mínima do topo da página**. Justamente para o usuário ter o espaço de clicar fora. Essa foi atualizada no último dia 3 de junho e você pode obter a versão dele deste repositório, [aqui](https://github.com/tanpinquan/dropdown_with_offset/blob/master/custom_dropdown.dart#L411). Coloquei como curiosidade, o link da linha da modificação do offset. O seu uso é semelhante ao código original que coloquei acima, porém com a propriedade `offsetAmount` definida.

Para o seu caso, uma combinação dessas duas propriedades deve resolver. Colocar uma distância mínima para o topo da tela e/ou uma altura máxima para a lista de itens. Porém essa solução deve ser atualizada com cada modificação do Flutter e um dia no futuro (Quem sabe?) a equipe incorpore essa solução à biblioteca oficial.